# Searching strings for a partial match in sparql

Tags: sparql

Suppose I have an RDF graph that looks like the following:

```
entity1 [
    title [ obect1.svg]       
    description [
         "This is sentence 1.  This is sentence 2." ]
         ] .
entity2 [
    title [ obect2.svg]       
    description [
         "This is sentence 3.  This is sentence 4." ]
].
entity3 [
    title [ obect3.svg]       
    description [
         "This is sentence 1.  This is sentence 4." ]
] .
```

How would I write a query to find This is sentence 2?

Answer (score 2):

See http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-strings

Functions `REGEX` or `CONTAINS`.